# nesting functionality missing in section type structure after feed-me import

Tags: structure, sections, plugin-feedme

i create an new section from type structure.

when i manually add the entries and nest it everything works as aspected.
[image]

after importing my entries with feed-me and the option create parents if not exist the nesting is gone and i cant set test as parent in Content-test. when i check the section.yaml its still of type structure.

[image]

there is for me no way to get the nesting back.

only option now is to recreate the section.

anyone although having this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: screenshot of Craft's order-by dropdown]

Check the sort order dropdown at the top right of the index page to make sure you're on "Structure".

Comment: To add to James' answer, make sure you are not on _All entries_ but you have the structure selected :)

Comment: jep that was it. never actually saw that option. thanks a lot!